# change checkout page headings in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How can I change the  **checkout page headings** in Magento?

[image: checkout headings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, the simplest way is to change this headings in translation file (`Mage_Checkout.csv`). But if you want to use some custom labels, and you don't want to conflict with native translations for other blocks on checkout, you should update those labels:

these classes are located in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage`.

- Billing.php
- Shipping.php
- Payment.php
- Review.php

You can change label in `_construct()` method.
For example:

```
class Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Review extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->getCheckout()->setStepData('review', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Order Review'), // your custom label here
            'is_show'   => $this->isShow()
        ));
        parent::_construct();

        $this->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
    }
}
```

You can override those classes.